# WP7/XNA/Silverlight: How can I draw a spriteBatch after I draw a TriangleStrip?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xna

I want to draw the Silverlight-PhoneApplicationPage and its controls on top of some squares which I draw as TriangleStrips.

The other way around is works perfectly fine, but the squares are drawn on top of my controls - I do something like this in my Draw-function:

```
private void OnDraw(object sender, GameTimerEventArgs e)
{
    // Clean up device
    graphicsDevice.Clear(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color.Black);
    graphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.AlphaBlend;
    RasterizerState stat = new RasterizerState();
    stat.CullMode = CullMode.None;
    graphicsDevice.RasterizerState = stat;

    // Draw Silverlight UI element to Texture
    elementRenderer.Render();

    // Draw Silverlight UI element
    spriteBatch.Begin();
    spriteBatch.Draw(elementRenderer.Texture, Vector2.Zero, Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color.White);
    spriteBatch.End();

    effect.Texture = tex;
    effect.TextureEnabled = true;
    effect.World = BillboardMatrix;
    effect.View = view;
    effect.Projection = projection;

    foreach (EffectPass pass in effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
    {
        pass.Apply();
        graphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives<VertexPositionTexture>(PrimitiveType.TriangleStrip, vertices, 0, 2);
    }
}
```

If I try to draw the spriteBatch after the Triangles I get this error:
"NotSupportedException - XNA Framework Reach profile requires TextureAddressMode to be Clamp when using texture sizes that are not powers of two."

```
private void OnDraw(object sender, GameTimerEventArgs e)
{
    // Clean up device
    graphicsDevice.Clear(Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color.Black);
    graphicsDevice.BlendState = BlendState.AlphaBlend;
    RasterizerState stat = new RasterizerState();
    stat.CullMode = CullMode.None;
    graphicsDevice.RasterizerState = stat;

    // Draw Silverlight UI element to Texture
    elementRenderer.Render();

    effect.Texture = tex;
    effect.TextureEnabled = true;
    effect.World = BillboardMatrix;
    effect.View = view;
    effect.Projection = projection;

    foreach (EffectPass pass in effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
    {
        pass.Apply();
        graphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives<VertexPositionTexture>(PrimitiveType.TriangleStrip, vertices, 0, 2);
    }

    // Draw Silverlight UI element
    spriteBatch.Begin();
    spriteBatch.Draw(elementRenderer.Texture, Vector2.Zero, Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Color.White);
    spriteBatch.End();
}
```

I also tried to set `graphicsDevice.SamplerStates[i] = SamplerState.LinearClamp;` but it didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now - I changed the CullMode:

```
stat.CullMode = CullMode.None;
```

to

```
stat.CullMode = CullMode.CullCounterClockwiseFace;
```